# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS boot problem - (won't startup after install)

Tags: screen, startup, boot-failure

I installed 12.04 64-bit on my new PC. The installation says its completed, I got the CD out of the PC and then when it restarts it just goes to a purple screen and stays like that forever. I can't even get to the login screen. When I boot from Ubuntu installation CD there's no recovery mode option. What can I do? Please help.

My PC is:

- ASUS M5a97
- AMD Fx6100
- 8 GB RAM
- ATI RADEON 6670

Comment: Press `Esc` in purple screen and let us know last few messages in log while the system stucks

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS as well and the odd time when I boot, it does the same thing (purple screen) and then reboots, purple screen and cycles forever, never booting. I solved it by connecting my laptop to AC power.